# Subdomain routing node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a site where the code checks what subdomain the user is accessing from. I can get the host by running this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const host = req.get('host');
    const origin = req.get('origin');
    res.send(host)
})
```

And i get the result: localhost:5000.

But i want to make it so that if the user is accessing from domain1.com it uses one router, and if it is from domain2.com it uses another. here is the code im trying to use:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = express.Router();


app.set('view engine', 'ejs')


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const host = req.get('host');
    const origin = req.get('origin');
    if(host === "domain1.com:5000"){
        const test = require('./routes/test.js')
        app.use('/', test)
    }else if(host === "domain2.com:5000"){
        res.send("Domain2")
    }else{
        res.send(host)
    }
})

app.listen(5000)
```

**/routes/test.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.send("it Works")
})



module.exports = router
```

When i try accessing the domain1 it does not work, and i don't get any errors in console

Comment: `use()` is used to register routes and middleware.

It isn't used to modify the response to the *current* request.